# What version of stomp does Spring framework support

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket

Spring framework supports Stomp over WebSocket. (Stomp has 1.0, 1.1 and latest 1.2.)

My question is:

- What version (or versions) of stomp does Spring framework support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Framework supports versions `"v10"`, `"v11"` and `"v12"`, see [StompSubProtocolHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/66722afda0/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/StompSubProtocolHandler.java#L169)

Comment: Really appreciate  @Brian Clozel